# How can I update the following jquery to bring only the industry attribute?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, kendo-multiselect

I'm currently trying to call only fields with certain attributes. Since I'm no jquery expert, I took the "add all" button as a guide and updated it to serve my purpose. So far, I haven't received the results I was expecting.

Down below is the original "add - all" code which adds all "li" from the left side of a table to the right.

```
this.container.find(".add-all").click(function() {
            var options = that.element.find('option').not(":selected");
            if (that.availableList.children('li:hidden').length > 1) {
                that.availableList.children('li').each(function(i) {
                    if (jQuery(this).is(":visible")) jQuery(options[i-1]).attr('selected', 'selected'); 
                });
            } else {
                options.attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
            that._populateLists(that.element.find('option'));
            return false;
        });
```

This is the code that generates the "li".

```
_getOptionNode: function(option) {
        option = jQuery(option);
        var node = jQuery('<li class="ui-state-default ui-element "  title="'+option.text()+'" data-selected-value="' + option.val() + '" industry = "'+ option.attr("class")+'"  ><span class="ui-icon"/>'+option.text()+'<a href="#" class="action"><span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon"/></a></li>').hide();
        node.data('optionLink', option);
        return node;
```

I tried updating the "add all" code in order to call only the industry attribute. This is what I tried...

```
this.container.find(".add-auto").click(function() {
            var options = that.element.find('option').not(":selected");
            if (that.availableList.children('li:hidden').length > 1) {
                that.availableList.children('li').each(function(i) {
                    if (jQuery(this).is(":visible") && jQuery(this).find("[industry = 'auto']")) jQuery(options[i-1]).attr('selected', 'selected');
                });
            } else {
                that.availableList.children('li').each(function (i) {
                    if (jQuery(this).find("[industry = 'auto']")) jQuery(options[i-1]).attr('selected','selected');
                });
            }
            that._populateLists(that.element.find('option'));
            return false;
        });
```

This is what the inspect in the actual page brings up. Also , for some reason I'm getting an extra apostrophe in the industry = "auto'". Will this affect the end results? If so, how could I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Your picture says `industry="auto'"` there appears to be an extra single quote in there that your jQuery selector isn't looking for

Comment: In the essential, if I fix that, should the code work?

Comment: No idea, but it's worth a shot